# report regression result using stargazer to add separate column for standard error

Tags: r, output, regression, stargazer

I am trying to use `stargazer()` to export my regression result. I wanted to be able to report both coefficient and standard error in separate columns see this pic here:

[image]

However I can only get coefficient and standard error in the same row using single.row = TRUE. Is there something to achieve the desired result?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about getting all components that you need from the model output, store it as a dataframe and display this in `stargazer` style?

```
library(stargazer)
model<-lm(mpg~disp+factor(cyl), data=mtcars)
stargazer(model, type="text", omit="cyl")

results <- data.frame(Coefficient = summary(model)$coefficients[,1],
                      Standard_Error = summary(model)$coefficients[,2])

stargazer(results, title="Table 1: Results", summary=F, type = "text")

Table 1: Results
=======================================
             Coefficient Standard_Error
---------------------------------------
(Intercept)    29.535        1.427     
disp           -0.027        0.011     
factor(cyl)6   -4.786        1.650     
factor(cyl)8   -4.792        2.887     
---------------------------------------
```